# Java SQL Exception : Closed Resultset: next even though neither connection or resultset gets closed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Basically, I have the following method that would get me the id from an oracle table :

```
public Integer findByName(String name) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = Database.getConnection();
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {
        stmt.executeQuery("select id from artists where name='" + name + "'");
        return rs.next() ? rs.getInt(1) : null;
    }
}
```

And in the Main method where i try to test it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            ArtistController artists = new ArtistController();
            AlbumController albums = new AlbumController();


            artists.create("Radiohead", "United Kingdom");
            artists.create("Phoenix", "Romania");
            Database.commit();


            int radioheadId = artists.findByName("Radiohead");
            System.out.println(radioheadId);

            albums.create(radioheadId,"OK COMPUTER", 1977);
            albums.create(radioheadId, "Kid A", 2000);
            albums.create(radioheadId, "In Rainbows", 2007);

            Database.commit();


            Database.closeConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            Database.rollback();
        }
    }
```

I get the exception: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next even though as you can see I am closing neither the connection or the statement before rs and I do not understand why

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of the stacktrace, not just the one line that names the exception type.

Comment: I'm surprised that no exception is thrown for calling `getResultSet()` before executing a statement, that seems to be a violation of the JDBC requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your `try-with-resources` **does** `close` the `ResultSet`, but that isn't the real problem. You need to set-up the `Statement` ***before*** you execute it (and prefer `PreparedStatement` and bind parameters). Something like,

```
public Integer findByName(String name) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "select id from artists where name=?";
    Connection con = Database.getConnection();
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            return rs.next() ? rs.getInt(1) : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It actually works. Now my question is :  following your idea i am trying to get all the records that have a specific id and i am using ResultSetMetaData but i have an exception : statement handle not executed : getMetaData . The code is here : [link](https://pastebin.com/kMscXLKW)

Comment: @v_manoliu Ask another question; post the relevant code there. But first, make sure you are actually calling `executeQuery()` ***before*** you attempt to get the meta data.

Comment: Frisch . The link to the code is : [link](https://pastebin.com/kMscXLKW)

Comment: @v_manoliu Call `next()` before getting the meta data. The cursor is ***before*** the first result.

Comment: It says that the cursor is invalid

Comment: Your query has one column. You need to decide what you really want to achieve, and post another question.

Comment: The connection should also be in the try-with-resources.